# Electrostatics with Yukawa mass

Tags: electrostatics

I seem to have forgotten how to solve Laplace's equation when there is a Yukawa mass $\mu$.  I want to find the Yukawa potential due to a homogeneously charged sphere of radius $R$ and charge density $\rho$.

**My attempt**

I need to solve $(\nabla^2-\mu^2)\phi = -\rho$ inside and outside the sphere.  Since there is spherical symmetry, I can convert to spherical coordinates, and assume the potential $\phi$ has no angular dependence:

$$
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} (r\phi) - \mu^2 \phi = -\rho
$$

Outside the sphere, there is no charge, so I solve the homogenous equation giving the solution:
$$\phi_\text{out}(r) = A \frac{e^{-\mu r}}{r}+B \frac{e^{\mu r}}{r}$$

and inside the sphere, where there is charge density, I solve the inhomogenous equation, giving the solution:
$$\phi_\text{in}(r) = \frac{\rho}{\mu^2}+C \frac{e^{-\mu r}}{r}+D \frac{e^{\mu r}}{r}$$

**Problem**  I have four constants of integration ($A$, $B$, $C$, $D$) but only three pieces of information to fix them.

1. The potential should not blow up as $r\rightarrow\infty$: I must have $B=0$
2. It should not be singular as $r\rightarrow 0$: I must have $D=-C$.  And therefore,
   $$\phi_\text{in}(r) = \frac{\rho}{\mu^2} + 2 C \frac{\sinh( \mu r)}{r}$$
3. Also, I must have continuity at the surface of the sphere $r=R$: Then I have
   $$A=\big(\frac{\rho R}{\mu^2}+ 2 C \sinh \mu R\big)e^{\mu R}$$

My potential has an undetermined constant $C$;  What is the final piece of information that will fix $C$?

Comment: The gradient at the boundary of the sphere is also continuous.

Comment: Yes that's right, thanks!  This final piece of information implies $C=-\big[\rho  e^{-\mu R} (\mu  R+1)\big]/\big[2 \mu^3\big]$.